# Color specific bars in chart

Tags: pandas, plot

I built a bar chart (per year) and would like to highlight (change color) 2019 to 2021. Using color parameter changes all bars, not just these years.

```
rquantdiv = df4[(df4['Código'] == 1268)]
rquantdiv = rquantdiv.drop(columns='Código')
rquantdiv = rquantdiv.groupby(['ANO']).sum('PROCESSO')

print(rquantdiv)

fig_rquantdiv = rquantdiv.plot.bar(grid=True)

for p in fig_rquantdiv.patches:
    fig_rquantdiv.annotate(str(p.get_height()), (p.get_x() * 0.99, p.get_height() * 1.005))
```

Code to change color of specific years (bars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = {'ANO': [2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022],
        'PROCESSO': [10, 15, 18, 20, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Filter the DataFrame for the years you want to highlight
highlight_years = df[(df['ANO'] >= 2019) & (df['ANO'] <= 2021)]


ax = df.plot.bar(x='ANO', y='PROCESSO', grid=True)

# Change the color of bars for the highlighted years
for i, bar in enumerate(ax.patches):
    if df['ANO'].iloc[i] in highlight_years['ANO'].values:
        bar.set_facecolor('red')  # Here your choice color

for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(p.get_height()), (p.get_x() * 0.99, p.get_height() * 1.005))

plt.show()
```

**Output :**

[image]

You can change the color to any other color of your choice by replacing **red** with your preferred color.